# type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Tags: python, datetime, namespaces

I have gotten the following error:

> type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

On the following line:

```
date = datetime.datetime(int(year), int(month), 1)
```

Does anybody know the reason for the error?

I imported datetime with `from datetime import datetime` if that helps

Thanks

Answer (score 179, accepted):

For python 3.3

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
futuredate = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=10)
```

Comment: +1. I think this should be the correct answer because as far as I know, `import datetime` always causes problems, so I'm in favor of a solution which uses `from datetime import datetime`

Comment: This is the best answer. Other answers are confusing. This should have been the accepted answer.

Comment: I personally liked this one because it showed the correct usage of  timedelta when using the from X import Y method.

Answer (score 352):

Datetime is a module that allows for handling of dates, times and datetimes (all of which are datatypes). This means that `datetime` is both a top-level module as well as being a type within that module. This is confusing.

Your error is probably based on the confusing naming of the module, and what either you or a module you're using has already imported.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime
<module 'datetime' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/datetime.so'>
>>> datetime.datetime(2001,5,1)
datetime.datetime(2001, 5, 1, 0, 0)
```

But, if you import datetime.datetime:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
>>> datetime.datetime(2001,5,1) # You shouldn't expect this to work 
                                # as you imported the type, not the module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
>>> datetime(2001,5,1)
datetime.datetime(2001, 5, 1, 0, 0)
```

I suspect you or one of the modules you're using has imported like this:
 `from datetime import datetime`.

Comment: @Jean this is the fault of datetime shadowing its own module's name with one of its class names, not python's.

Comment: This is one of the most frustratingly silly aspects of `datetime`. The person who programmed it should do some refactoring.

Answer (score 29):

You should really import the module into its own **alias**.

```
import datetime as dt
my_datetime = dt.datetime(year, month, day)
```

The above has the following benefits over the other solutions:

- Calling the variable `my_datetime` instead of `date` reduces confusion since there is already a `date` in the datetime module (`datetime.date`).
- The module and the class (both called `datetime`) do not shadow each other.

Comment: To me this is really the best solution to avoid the repeated confusion between datetime... and datetime.datetime...

Answer (score 25):

You should use

```
date = datetime(int(year), int(month), 1)
```

Or change

```
from datetime import datetime
```

to

```
import datetime
```

Answer (score 8):

If you have used:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

Then simply write the code as:

```
date = datetime(int(year), int(month), 1)
```

But if you have used:

```
import datetime
```

then only you can write:

```
date = datetime.datetime(int(2005), int(5), 1)
```

Answer (score 5):

I run into the same error maybe you have already imported the module by using only `import datetime` so change  `from datetime import datetime` to only `import datetime`. It worked for me after I changed it back.

Comment: Is the `form` a typo? Seems like it should be `from`.

Answer (score 3):

```py
import time
import datetime
from datetime import date,timedelta
```

You must have imported `datetime` from `datetime`.

Answer (score 2):

I found this to be a lot easier

```
from dateutil import relativedelta
relativedelta.relativedelta(end_time,start_time).seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

**Avoid to write**:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.datetime.function()
```

**Solution No. 1**:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.function()
```

**Solution No. 2**:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.function()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply run the below command.

import datetime

datetime.fromtimestamp(details.start_date).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

Comment: I'm not sure that really answers the question the person wrote; a number of the other answers seem to address the key problem

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
from calendar import timegm
d = datetime.utcnow()
d = d.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
utc_time = time.strptime(d,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
epoch_time = timegm(utc_time)
```

Comment: Try to avoid code-only answers. You can [edit] your post to add some explanations and links to support your code.

Answer (score 0):

delete one datetime from:

```
date = datetime.datetime(int(year), int(month), 1)
```

and you get this:

```
date = datetime(int(year), int(month), 1)
```

you already imported the first one with this:

`from datetime import datetime`

so its redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I tried :

```
import datetime 
from datetime import timedelta
```

and it worked somewhat

Answer (score 0):

You should use dt.datetime instead of datetime.datetime.
It works very well like in the example below:

```
    import datetime as dt
    from datetime import datetime,timedelta


    string_date1="2023-11-22"
    date1=dt.datetime.strptime(string_date1, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
    print(date1)
    string_added_days="14";added_days=dt.timedelta(days=int(string_added_days))
    print(added_days)
    date_in_future=date1+added_days
    print(date_in_future)
```

Answer (score -4):

The Problem Is That You Are Using The Tag

```
from datetime
```

I had The Same Problem You Need To use It Like This Instead

```
import datetime
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. I am not a downvoter but suspect you are getting downvoted because this isn't completely correct, and you could make use of formatting tags to make your code references clearer.