# How to get date in dd/mm/yy format from a timestamp in excel using python

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, date, datetime

I am reading data from a excel sheet like this -

```
day1 = first_sheet.cell(row,26).value
```

I want to use this date for some other operations later but the data is coming in a float format which i find very confusing and unsuitable for debugging.

I tried using this --->>

```
day = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(day1, 0))
```

But i got this error --->>

> AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute
>   'datetime'

I am using python 2.7 Kindly help me out.

Comment: Will you please go through this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906402/type-object-datetime-datetime-has-no-attribute-datetime

Comment: Please always consider the case while importing modules. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
day1 = first_sheet.cell(row,26).value
d = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(int(day1), 0)
#convert date tuple in yy-mm-dd format
d = datetime.datetime(*(d[0:3]))
dStr = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```