# Add time to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, time, python-datetime

I have a date string like this and then use `strptime()` So its like this

```
my_time = datetime.datetime.strptime('07/05/15', '%m/%d/%Y')
```

and now I want to add 23 hours and 59 minutes to `my_time`

I have tried `.timedelta` but it doesn't work? How could I do this?

Comment: What is the code you are using? It works for me

Comment: Are you asking if code you have "tried" but haven't posted works?  If you know it doesn't work, what do you expect anyone to tell you about it without seeing the code?

Answer (score 14):

Add time afterwards; you can do so with the [`datetime.replace()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) to produce a new `datetime` object:

```
my_time = datetime.datetime.strptime('07/05/15', '%m/%d/%y')
my_time = my_time.replace(hour=23, minute=59)
```

The `datetime.strptime()` sets the hour and minute values to the default, `0`. Note that for a two-digit year (like `15`) you'd use `%y`, not `%Y`, which is for a four-digit year.

You could also use the [`datetime.combine()` class method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) to pair up a `date` and a `time` object:

```
my_time = datetime.datetime.strptime('07/05/15', '%m/%d/%y')
my_time = datetime.datetime.combine(my_time.date(), datetime.time(23, 59))
```

If you feel you must use a `timedelta()`, take into account that adding it will again produce a new `datetime` object. You could use augmented assignment to add it 'in-place':

```
my_time = datetime.datetime.strptime('07/05/15', '%m/%d/%y')
my_time += datetime.timedelta(hours=23, minutes=59)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> my_time = datetime.datetime.strptime('07/05/15', '%m/%d/%y')
>>> my_time.replace(hour=23, minute=59)
datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 5, 23, 59)
>>> datetime.datetime.combine(my_time.date(), datetime.time(23, 59))
datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 5, 23, 59)
>>> my_time + datetime.timedelta(hours=23, minutes=59)
datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 5, 23, 59)
```

Comment: if you need to add an amount that is negative or more than one day then only the `timedelta()` solution would work.

Answer (score 10):

Firstly, based on the date string you are providing, the `format` seems to be wrong , you should use `%y` (small y) for 2 digit years, `%Y` (capital Y) is for 4 digit years.

Then you can add time to my_time using timedelta as follows, but the addition operation produces a new datetime object, does not change the `my_time` in place.

Hence, you will need to assign it back to your `my_time` like this -

```
>>> import datetime

>>> my_time = datetime.datetime.strptime('07/05/15', '%m/%d/%y')
>>> my_time = my_time + datetime.timedelta(hours=23,minutes=59)
>>> my_time
datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 5, 23, 59)
```

Comment: i dont know why but it throws error ```AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'```. My code looks like ```from datetime import datetime; newTime = passedTime + datetime.timedelta()```

Comment: this answer helped me to solve that issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/12906456/9277453

Comment: If anyone has the same error that Alexey Nikonov had: You need to do `import datetime; newTime = passedTime + datetime.timedelta()`. Alexey essentially did `import datetime; newTime = passedTime + datetime.datetime.timedelta()` because of how he structured his import as `from datetime import datetime`.

Answer (score 0):

pandas way:

```py
import pandas as pd 
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(ddf['time']) + pd.Timedelta('16:00:00')
```