# How to add time to a time string

Tags: python, time

I would like to add a certain time to a formatted time string in python. For this I tried the following

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

timestemp_Original = '2021-07-13T00:15:00Z'
timestemp_Added1 =  '2021-07-13T00:15:00Z' + timedelta(minutes=15)
timestemp_Added2 = timestemp_Original + datetime.timedelta(hours=0, minutes=15)
```

but this leads to error messages (I took it from here [How to add hours to current time in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685201/how-to-add-hours-to-current-time-in-python) and [Add time to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31218508/add-time-to-datetime)). Can aynone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add time to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31218508/add-time-to-datetime) Nowhere in the linked questions do they add a `timedelta` to a string. They always _parse_ the string to a `datetime` object using `strptime` and _then_ they add the `timedelta`

Comment: But I would like to know if this is directly possible without converting it

Comment: @PeterBe, without converting to `datetime`?

Comment: No, it is not possible. You're going to have to parse the elements of that string to figure out what needs to be added to what, and if you're doing that you might as well use the `datetime.strptime` function to parse it instead of reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, You need to convert `str` to `datetime` with a specific format of string_date and then use `timedelta(minutes=15)`.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
timestemp_Original = '2021-07-13T00:15:00Z'
timestemp_Added1 = datetime.strptime(timestemp_Original, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ") + timedelta(minutes=15)
print(timestemp_Added1)

# If you want to get as original format
print(timestemp_Added1.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"))
# 2021-07-13T00:30:00Z
```

---

```
2021-07-13 00:30:00
```