# Datetime has no attribute datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I want to return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_visit,"%Y-%m-%d") into my function read_file but python keeps saying that datetime.datetime has no attribute datetime? In the function where I return it´s working. Pls help anyone.

```
return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_visit,"%Y-%m-%d") 




def read_file(date): 

  all_animals = list() 

  day = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_visit,"%Y-%m-%d").isoweekday()


  datetime.datetime.strptime(date_visit,"%Y-%m-%d") 


  workingday = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906402/type-object-datetime-datetime-has-no-attribute-datetime

Comment: Possible duplicate of [type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906402/type-object-datetime-datetime-has-no-attribute-datetime)

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `import datetime.datetime` by `import datetime`

Answer (score 0):

Of course `datetime.datetime` does not have the attribute `datetime`. You should use it like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.strptime(...)
```

Or:

```
import datetime

datetime.datetime.strptime(...)
```

To use `datetime.datetime.strptime()` you need to import the whole module:

```
import datetime
```

The second `datetime` is a type in the first one, and it has `strptime()` function. For more details please check this link:

[datetime — Basic date and time types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#module-datetime)