# datetime.datetime has no attribute datetime

Tags: python

I keep having an issue with the module datetime at this section of the code whenever i run it, it should add the time to the alarm manager from the datetime-local input from the html part. But whenever the text and date are added an error of datetime.datetime is not an attribute of datetime.

```
from datetime import datetime

alarm_datetime = datetime.datetime(*alarm_tmp)
```

Comment: Perhaps `alarm_datetime = datetime.datetime(*alarm_tmp)` should just be `alarm_datetime = datetime(*alarm_tmp)`? You've already imported `datetime` from the `datetime` package already, so you don't need to do `datetime.datetime(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you do

```
from datetime import datetime
```

You don't need to

```
alarm_datetime = datetime.datetime(*alarm_tmp)
```

Instead, just do

```
alarm_datetime = datetime(*alarm_tmp)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should only use datetime and not datetime.datetime in your code.
To use your code:

```
@app.route('/',methods=['POST','GET'])      #adding two methods posting and getting
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':    #submitting form
        task_content = request.form['content'] #create new task from user input
        alarm_content = request.form['alarm']
        alarm_tmp = alarm_content.replace('T', '-').replace(':', '-').split('-')
        alarm_tmp = [int(v) for v in alarm_tmp]
        alarm_datetime = datetime(*alarm_tmp)
        task = Table(content=task_content,alarm=alarm_content)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue stems from the import and usage.

```
from datetime import datetime
```

Later on in your index() method you have

```
alarm_datetime = datetime.datetime(*alarm_tmp)
```

Here is an SO question that has an additional info on the error: [type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12906456/8828479)