# Adding X days to a date

Tags: python, datetime, google-colaboratory

I'm making a stock price prediction LSTM model.

I've got two dates from an input:

```
from datetime import datetime    
data1 = datetime.strptime(data1input, '%Y%m%d').date()
data2 = datetime.strptime(data2input, '%Y%m%d').date()
```

The difference in days between the two dates is 80% of the whole period, so I need to know the whole period in days and its 20%:

```
whole_days=round((date1.days * 100)/80)
print(whole_time)
left_days = round(whole_time * .2)
print(left_time)
```

Now, I'd like to know the resulting date by adding `left_time` days to `data2`. But it gives me an error. What is the correct code to do this?

```
data_left = data2 + datetime.timedelta(days=left_time)

type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'
```

Comment: Have a look at [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906402/type-object-datetime-datetime-has-no-attribute-datetime).

Comment: just use `from datetime import timedelta` and use `timedelta(days=left_time)` instead of `datetime.timedelta(days=left_time)`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to convert the input dates to ordinal and subtract them:

```
data1_ord = data1.toordinal()
data2_ord = data2.toordinal()
percent80_days = data2_ord - data1_ord
percent80_days
```

So I just worked with ordinal dates and converted the last ordinal to a date
It worked!

```
percent100_days=round((percent80_days * 100)/80)
percent20_days = round(percent100_days * .2)
data3_ord = data2_ord + percent20_days
data3 = datetime.fromordinal(data3_ord).date()
print(data3)
```