# How do I turn different date formats into the same?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, data-preprocessing

I have a column, 'StartDate' which has 2 types of formats for displaying the dates. The first is `'25/12/2022'`, and the second `datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0)`. So the first type of value does have the apostrophe and the second doesn't. How can I turn all of these values into the datetime type, formatted as `dd/mm/yyyy`?

Using the `pd.to_datetime()` has resulted in `NaT` values when the input is `'datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0)'`, but does result in a datetime type when the input is `'25/12/2022'`, which is something I haven't been able to figure out.

`pd.to_datetime` results in `NaT` when I the input is `datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 30, 0, 0)` and does return a datetime when the input is `01/10/2024`. I tried splitting the column into the datetimes and strings, but couldn't get it right.

I checked the amount of unique values in the beginning, which is 611. If I use `pd.to_datetime`, this is reduced to 509. This results in a lot of issues further down the line. All of the values which aren't parsed are like `datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0)`.

Comment: Do you want all the data to be strings or all the data to be datetime?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime` works for both types. What version of `pandas` are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.5.3!

Answer (score 1):

In my case I'm not getting `Nat` as you are suggesting.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['25/12/2022', datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 30, 0, 0)]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
print(df)


     date
0 2022-12-25
1 2023-12-30
```

Comment: This code snippet results in a error for me:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 4
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 from datetime import datetime
----> 4 df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['25/12/2022', datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 30, 0, 0)]})
      5 df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
      6 print(df)

AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Comment: @RobinKeij: I'm not getting this error. Maybe the following link help you resolve the issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906402/type-object-datetime-datetime-has-no-attribute-datetime